# Why by using loop and using matrix-wise operation return different result?

Tags: matlab

For example with code below, `D` and `D2` is not the same. Anyone can point out what the mistake here?

```
m=100;
n=100;
X=repmat(1:m,[n 1]);
Y=repmat((1:n)',[1 m]);
D=((((X/m)-0.1)^2).*X) - ((((Y/n)-00.33)^2).*Y); %matrix-wise

D2=zeros(m,n);
for x=1:m
    for y=1:n
        D2(x,y)=((((x/m)-0.1)^2)*x) - ((((y/n)-00.33)^2)*y);
    end
end
isequal(D,D2)
```

Comment: Use the element-wise power operator `.^` in the first segment.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yep that was it, thank you! But I wonder why is that matter is this case? Didn't `^2` will square all the elements in the matrix too?

Comment: `^` takes square of a matrix. `.^` takes square of each element of the matrix.